# Difficulty in finding the Region names in AWS rds

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, rds

How to get the names of all the rds instances in AWS using a boto script. I want to write a python script that fetches all the regions and then displays their dbinstances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should give you all of the available regions for RDS.

```
import boto.rds
regions = boto.rds.regions()
```

Which would return a list of `RegionInfo` objects like this.

```
[RegionInfo:us-east-1,
 RegionInfo:cn-north-1,
 RegionInfo:ap-northeast-1,
 RegionInfo:eu-west-1,
 RegionInfo:ap-southeast-1,
 RegionInfo:ap-southeast-2,
 RegionInfo:us-west-2,
 RegionInfo:us-gov-west-1,
 RegionInfo:us-west-1,
 RegionInfo:eu-central-1,
 RegionInfo:sa-east-1]
```

If you then wanted to connect to one particular region, say `eu-west-1` you could do this:

```
region = regions[6]
conn = region.connect()
```

or even:

```
conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region(region.name)
```