# amazon ses getting error result = conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(), AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_raw_email'

Tags: python, amazon-ses

I am trying to send raw email using ses and getting error result = conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(), AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_raw_email',  Can you please take look? Thanks a lot.

```
import boto.ses
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


def send_ses():
    to_emails = ['contact.ranvijay@gmail.com']
    COMMASPACE = ', '
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'test'
    msg['From'] = 'contact.ranvijay@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to_emails)
    # msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
    filename = '/Users/Mac/test/products/error_csv/price_upload_error_2016-05-10 19:50:06.868506.csv'

    attachment = open(filename, 'rb').read()
    part = MIMEApplication(attachment)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='test.csv')
    msg.attach(part)

    try:
        conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region(
                'US-EAST-1',
                aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY
        )
    except Exception as e:
        return e.__str__()

    result = conn.send_raw_email(msg.as_string(),
                                 source=msg['From'],
                                 destinations=to_emails
                                 )

    return result if 'ErrorResponse' in result else ''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_ses()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `conn.send_raw_email` and get a response that you are trying to access the .send_raw_email of a NoneType. Therefore, `conn == None`. You should check for that. The [docs](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/ses.html) for boto.ses.connect_to_region say it returns None if you give an invalid region name. From [this list of regions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28089857/733092) it looks like your problem is your region name should be in lower case instead of upper.

Answer (score 0):

if you using a python under 2.5 you should checking your env for BOTO because some region not supported from aws SES for python under 2.5 version for now.

you can check ur region support in your shell if you using boto

```
$python
>>> from boto import ses
>>> ses.regions()
[RegionInfo:us-east-1] #this is region supported for python version
```